# How to set a default value in an IF snippet?

Tags: bash, solaris

I have the following snippet in a bash script written in Solaris 10:

```
printf "port(389)="
read PORT
  if [[ $PORT == "" ]]; then
     PORT=389
  fi
```

What I am trying to get that if the user hits the enter key, the Port should be set to 389.
The snippet above does not seem to be working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"?

Comment: Works fine here. You're doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly what you asked, but Solaris has a set of utilities for this sort of thing.

```
PORT=`/usr/bin/ckint -d 389 -p 'port(389)=' -h 'Enter a port number'`
```

Check out the other /usr/bin/ck* utilities to prompt the user for other types of data, including things like files or user names.

Comment: This is actually what I was trying to get to. Wonderful thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This prompts the user for input and if enter is pressed by itself, sets the value of `port` to a default of "389":

```
read -rp "port(389)=" port
port="${port:-389}"
```

Comment: I could not paste the hole code in here because it is a part of a bigger script that deals with creating certificates for a Directory Server. But I am using "certutil" for Directory Server to accept inputs from user based on questions like "Organization", "City", "Country", etc. Port is one of them. 
Used in the following way:
$DSBIN/certutil -d $BASE_DIR/`hostname`/alias -P slapd- -x -S -n $NAME -s cn=$CN,cn=$PORT,st=$STATE,C=$COUNTRY,L="$CITY" -t CTu,u,u -v $MONTH
with my original if statement, the system is throwing a "bad database" error and this happens if one ore more entries are invalid

Comment: In reality, my snippet and your snippet function essentially identically (one exception is that mine has the `-r` option for `read`). You might try putting a `set -x` before and a `set +x` after the section of your code that is causing problems. This will cause a trace to be displayed which shows variable expansions among other things. It might help track down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `-e` to `read` then you can use `-i` to specify an initial value for the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If the user enters nothing then `$PORT` is replaced with nothing - the ancient convention for making this work with the original Bourne shell is:

```
if [ "x$PORT" == "x" ]; then
```

Though more modern shells (i.e. actual bash, but not Solaris 10 /bin/sh which is
an ancient Bourne shell) should be able to deal with:

```
if [[ "$PORT" == "" ]]; then
```

or even

```
if [[ -z "$PORT" ]]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with just the shell
 -- try parameter substitution:

```
read port
port=${port:-389}
```